# Why are all my scripts transferring as MIME type text/html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, mime-types

I work on a large node.js/Angular.js application. We use grunt to recompile public scripts and markup. Most of the time, I have no problems running the server locally. Every time I make changes, I run `grunt dev`, then start the server with `npm start`. If there's ever a problem with my code, grunt catches it and warns me about it before I start the server. However, every once in a while, I run my commands, refresh the page, and all of my dozens of scripts transfer as MIME type text/html instead of text/javascript, and the page loads nothing.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < environment-provider.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < promise-service.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:"http://localhost:3083/components/underscore/underscore.js". (index):62
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < underscore.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:"http://localhost:3083/components/spinner-button/spinner-button.js". (index):64
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3083/components/util/sa-util.js". (index):63
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < sa-util.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < spinner-button.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3083/bower_components/sport-ng/deferred/deferred-directive.js". (index):68
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3083/bower_components/sport-ng/datepicker/datepickerDirective.js". (index):69
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3083/bower_components/sport-ng/alerts/alertsService.js". (index):66
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < alertsService.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3083/bower_components/sport-ng/confirmDelete/confirmDeleteService.js". (index):67
```

When I open one of these script files in Chrome development tools, it shows me whatever is in my public/layout.html file. This problem persists for a while (usually the rest of the day), and I avoid it by switching to a new directory and recloning from github. When I switch back to that directory later, the problem is usually gone. Recently, I've grown more desperate. The problem is somehow following me between directories now, and I don't understand what's triggering this or how to stop it. Adding `type="text/javascript"` to my script tags doesn't seem to help, and I can't seem to recreate the problem. From the little I've been able to dig up on forums, it seems like it's an Angular problem.

The node.js framework that we're using to organize the app and serve files is [Nokomis](http://github.com/sportngin/nokomis). The layout file is dynamically generated by grunt to include a set of modules that this app uses. Grunt only updates the paths to those modules, though. The rest of the Angular files are served with simple script references.

```
<script src="/components/environment/environment-provider.js"></script>
<script src="/components/promise/promise-service.js"></script>
<script src="/components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/components/util/sa-util.js"></script>
<script src="/components/spinner-button/spinner-button.js"></script>
```

From the package.json:

```
"grunt": "0.4.1",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-compass": ">=0.1.3",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "0.4.x",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.7.x",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "0.2.x",
"grunt-exec": "0.4.x",
...
"engines": {
"node": ">=0.8.0",
"npm": ">=1.1.21"
},
```

Does anyone have advice for how to fix or prevent this problem?

Comment: It'd help to see the code you're using to serve up static files and what module versions you're using.

Comment: Do the files actually exist on the server? I'm thinking it's possible they throw a 404 error and the server serves the 404 page instead of the actual scripts.

Comment: Yes. All the files are there and have the correct contents. Until this error randomly happens, everything works fine.

Comment: Are you using a server to serve your .js files, or are you picking them up from the local file system?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a server.

Comment: Sounds to me like your web server isn't serving the content properly and it's sending the wrong MIME type header for the files being retrieved.

Comment: Ok, but why does it only do this some of the time? What triggers it, and what makes it decide to stop?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Nokomis's server. It's a node server.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to specify mime-types in nokomis...  It isn't exactly documented though so I might have missed something(?) -- you might just have to read the source to figure out how it is deciding which mime-type to send.

Comment: Ok, I resolved the issue. It turned out to be a problem with `pac`. Pac had an old version which was having all sorts of conflict with the newer code. (Sorry about the lack of nokomis documentation...I'll talk to the guy who wrote it and get him to fix that.) So the moral to the story is to keep your modules updated, I guess.